# How to quickly remove identical geometries from a geodataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, geopandas

I perform a geodataframe modification on the items during the **for** loop with **itertools.combinations()**. I check that there are no duplicate geometries, LineString in my case. If yes I delete one of them.

The pandas **drop_duplicates()** method does not work here because we are dealing with spatial geometries with point coordinates that may be distributed differently and yet represented by the same LineString.

```
import geopandas
import itertools

gdf = geopandas.read_file('example.geojson')
for a, b in itertools.combinations(gdf.geometry, 2):
    if a.equals(b) == True:
        try:
            gdf.drop(gdf[gdf['geometry'] == b].index.values, inplace=True)
        except:
            continue

gdf.to_file('example.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

This code works well but I have files that can be very large. For large files the execution time is very long. Is there a faster method?

I was thinking of using **numpy** by storing all geometries in a matrix. But I'm not sure how to use the equals() method (from [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)) with numpy on the matrix. Thanks for your help.

geodataframe from `example.geojson` looks like :

```
                                               geometry  
0       LINESTRING (42.70275 9.94481, 42.70030 9.94783)  
1       LINESTRING (42.70030 9.94783, 42.70275 9.94481)  
2       LINESTRING (42.70275 9.94481, 42.69700 9.97133)  
3       LINESTRING (42.69700 9.97133, 42.70275 9.94481)  
4      LINESTRING (42.60179 10.34216, 42.70030 9.94783) 
...
```

> **A SOLUTION**.
> Here is a complete solution inspired by @DanielKonstantinov solution with `deduplicate`. We take as input a GeoDataFrame or GeoSeries and return it modified.

```py
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

def solution(frame):
    linestring = frame.geometry
    coordinates = [list(x.coords) for x in linestring]
    matrix = np.array(coordinates)
    result = deduplicate(matrix)
    final_result = [list(map(tuple, pair)) for pair in result.tolist()]
    lines = [LineString(pair) for pair in final_result]
    return gpd.GeoSeries(lines)
```

Comment: could you upload a small `example.geojson` file to work with?

Comment: Is gdf.geometry hashable? Can you use nunique? Eliminating duplicates by checking every combination is going to be extremly inefficient because computer science, plus you're modifying the container you are iterating over.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Thanks. But no `nunique` does not work because they are geometries, I guess. For example the first two LineString in the table are different for pandas but identical from a geospatial point of view, because they have the same couple of coordinates.

Comment: You need a hashable type so you can use a set. I got an error from "pip install geopandas" so I'll just point out that a set provides O(n) duplicate detection, while combinations gives O(n^2). Also, don't modify the container while you are iterating over it -- make it a generator that yields a new collection, or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np


def deduplicate(geo_data: np.ndarray # shape == (N, 4)
        ) -> np.ndarray:             # deduplicated data with origin order
    data = geo_data.reshape(-1, 2, 2)
    dt = f'f{data.itemsize}' # f4 or f8
    data = data.view([('x', dt), ('y', dt)]) 
    # eliminate differences
    ixs = np.argsort(data, -2, order=('x', 'y'))
    data_no_df = np.take_along_axis(data, ixs, axis=-2) # sorted by 'x' then by 'y'
    # get unique
    unique_sorted_data, uni_ixs = np.unique(data_no_df, True, axis=0)
    uni_ixs.sort() # inplace sort 1d-array
    data_deduplicated = geo_data[uni_ixs] # unique, originally ordered and shaped
    return data_deduplicated


def _test():
    geo_data = np.array([[42.70275,  9.94481, 42.7003 ,  9.94783],
                         [42.7003 ,  9.94783, 42.70275,  9.94481],
                         [42.70275,  9.94481, 42.697  ,  9.97133],
                         [42.697  ,  9.97133, 42.70275,  9.94481],
                         [42.60179, 10.34216, 42.7003 ,  9.94783]])
    data_deduplicated = deduplicate(geo_data)
    print(data_deduplicated)

>>> _test()
[[42.70275  9.94481 42.7003   9.94783]
 [42.70275  9.94481 42.697    9.97133]
 [42.60179 10.34216 42.7003   9.94783]]

large_data = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(1000, 4)).astype('d')

%timeit deduplicate(large_data)
1.98 ms ± 9.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works fine and really faster. I have learned a lot. In `deduplicate` I guess `x` in _take_along_axis_ is `data`. I upload a global solution for the problem in the post.

Comment: @Tim I'm glad I could help! Fixed a typo. When you have time, could you please edit the title? I guess the main problem wasn't speeding up itertoools.combinations. In my opinion, what you mentioned in the comment was much more important. It was a challenge for me to understand how to work with structures like yours, in particular how to sort them. Thank you for this question)

Comment: Yes you are right ! I changed the title, even if it's not exactly that, it's better I think. In general, I may now process my tables with numpy and avoid pandas methods, numpy is really impressive.